# Active Records - Userr_id - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i am new to rails so any help would be much appreciated. I have the models users and adverts. User has_many adverts and Advert belongs to a user.

> Question: when a user creates an advert i want the created advert to be automatically linked to the current user that created the advert. I am unsure how to go about this

i know how to assign advert to a user in the console

```
advert = Advert.first
advert.userr_id = 3
advert.save
```

but i am unsure how to implement this in my controller. Any directional advise would be much appreciated

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150330233948) do

  create_table "adverts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "category_jobtype_id"
    t.integer  "category_positiontype_id"
    t.integer  "salarystart"
    t.integer  "salaryend"
    t.integer  "category_country_id"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "town"
    t.string   "postcode"
    t.integer  "category_editorialapproval_id"
    t.integer  "category_applicationrequest_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "userr_id"
  end

  create_table "userrs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                    default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",       default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",            default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "companyname"
    t.integer  "category_businesstype_id"
  end

  add_index "userrs", ["email"], name: "index_userrs_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "userrs", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_userrs_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

models

```
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Userr < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :adverts
end
```

controller: Advert

```
class AdvertsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_action :set_advert, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @adverts = Advert.all
    respond_with(@adverts)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@advert)
  end

  def new
    @advert = Advert.new
    respond_with(@advert)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @advert = Advert.new(advert_params)
    @advert.save
    respond_with(@advert)
  end

  def update
    @advert.update(advert_params)
    respond_with(@advert)
  end

  def destroy
    @advert.destroy
    respond_with(@advert)
  end

  private
    def set_advert
      @advert = Advert.find(params[:id])
    end

    def advert_params
      params.require(:advert).permit(:title, :content, :category_jobtype_id, :category_positiontype_id, :salarystart, :salaryend, :category_country_id, :city, :town, :postcode, :category_editorialapproval_id, :category_applicationrequest_id)
    end
end
```

controller: Userr

any help will be much appreciated. A book recommendation or a tutorial will be helpful....many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the user object accessible, basically you can just do:

```
def create
  @advert = Advert.create(advert_params)
  user.adverts << @advert
  respond_with(@advert)
end
```

When you use the `has_many` method, the model receives some methods "for free". The `<<()` method is just one of them. You can find out many things about associations and these methods automatically generated [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: thanks @Tiago but it doesn't seem to work. when a user creates an advert it is not assigning the user to the advert. the Advert still has a user_id in the console stated as 'nil'